# Chrome 61, chrome driver 2.32,Uncaught WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498513

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless, chrome-web-driver

With latest Chrome 61 and Chrome driver 2.32, unable to start chrome in headless mode in node js environment with selenium-webdriver 3.50. Getting the error below:

> Uncaught WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498513 (2c63aa53b2c658de596ed550eb5267ec5967b351),platform=Linux 3.13.0-112-generic x86_64)

The same thing is working in chrome 59 and 60. Is there any issue with latest chrome and webdriver ??

Comment: I am seeing the same error with selenium 3.40, Chrome 61 and chromedriver 2.32 on Linux. I am not running in headless mode. Following the chromium recommendations did not help: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/chrome-doesn-t-start

Comment: The latest `selenium-webdriver` package version is 3.5.0. There's no 3.50. I installed the latest `selenium-webdriver` and was able to run Chrome 61 without any issue. This question needs a [mcve].

Comment: Chrome driver 2.33 was released a few days ago. Worth trying it out.

Comment: The earlier attempt I mention was with chromedriver 2.32. Worked just fine.